# How to stop object from saving without adding an error? ruby on rails question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a custom validation. 
I want that when the validation fails, it will stop the object from being saved.

How can I do that without adding an error to the object (`error.add(:attribute)`)  ?

Thanks,

Oded

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to add an error when a validation fails? If it's not associated with an attribute use add_to_base

Comment: thanks add_to_base did the job!

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods defined in [ActiveModel::Validations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-invalid-3F) `valid?` and `invalid?`. These methods depend of the errors objects being populated in case validation fails.

I don't understand why you would want to override that behaviour. But, to answer the question, one way you can achieve that is having a Boolean attribute defined in the class you're validating and setting it to true or false in your validation. And saving or not saving based on that attribute.